# rsync delete after file hasn't existed for X days

Tags: backup, hard-drive, rsync

I have the following rsync command:

```
0 0  * * *  rsync -av --delete /media/VIDEOS/ /media/lacie1/backup/videos/
```

I want to set it so instead of doing a replication like what it's doing now, it does a normal backup and only deletes file from the destination only after they haven't been found on the source for X days (like 7 days). This is to give a larger window of recovery if files go missing, but without keeping loads of duplicate files as the files being backed up get moved around a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel; for example [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) is rsync based and can do what you need, among many other things.

Comment: brilliant stuff!